# Telerik Loading Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radajaxloadingpanel

I have a problem with Telerik Loading Panel My Problem goes on like this: I have a user control which there is a placeholder and a Rad Menu item which I am loading on a aspx page, here on the menu item click I have to load another user control in the placeholder,but here my loading panel is not loading on the menu click can please someone help me on this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Description does not gonna work here, please provide your code as well.

Comment: Ensure you are acually using AJAX to get your user control. RadAjaxLoadingPanel shows up either if the LoadingPanelID of a RadAjaxManager/RadAjaxManagerProxy is set, or the LoadingPanelID of a RadAjaxPanel is set, and that setting/panel is used to generate a partial postback. Alternatively, you can show() and hide() it via your own JS.